# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 GPS coordinates as center

Tags: google-maps, gps, center

Iv'd been searching All over the web for a solution to this, and Im still Unable to find any solve for it, iv'd been in googles own libery to find this.

I want the extract coordinates, from the GPS to use as center of my google maps so when your in fx. Copenhagen at Kongs nytorv you would get that position as center.

I have some options for my map here:

```
var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.674, 12.403),
      zoom: 10,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: false,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: true,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        }
    };
```

right now i have a static position as center.
But i cant find where to pull the information from

I keep on trying to solve this problem so we all get a solution the problem if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example from google docs

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

here is the code, in case this link is broken:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--
    Include the maps javascript with sensor=true because this code is using a
    sensor (a GPS locator) to determine the user's location.
    See: https://developers.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#SpecifyingSensor
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }

      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
          content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cant this be tested on a localhost since my is keep sending an error.

Just to add i have the newest version of chrome so i support html5

Comment: Thx i found out that it was my browser blocking the sensor so i open up the access and now it works Thanks